# How to wirelessly mirror a MacBook onto a smart tv without Apple TV?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, appletv

It seems like Apple wants me to spend 200 USD on an Apple TV just to wirelessly mirror my MacBook's display onto my smart tv.

Is there really no way to get around this? I'm not afraid of technical solutions.

Answer (score 2):

After I did upgrade to Catalina, I can use **AirPlay** **button in the menu bar**.

[image]

The only requirement is that TV and MBP are on the same network. Picture quality on Macbook will be lower than on TV actually.
Tested with ***MBP Late 2016 (10.15.3)*** and ***LG 43um7500pla (4K TV)***.

Comment: The airplay button does not show the "Airplay To" section for me.  I'm also on Catalina and have an LG 4k OLED TV (2020).  Not sure what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

No, there are in fact other ways to do this wirelessly. However, the methods I've seen require the installation of software and may be restricted to certain brands of TV.

By way of example, you can install [Mirror for Samsung TV](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mirror-for-samsung-tv/id1107644799?mt=12) to mirror whatever is on your Mac to any Samsung TV produced in the past five or so years.

Likewise, you can do the same with:

- [Mirror for LG TV](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mirror-for-lg-tv/id1152966194?mt=12)
- [Mirror for Panasonic TV](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mirror-for-panasonic-tv/id1148522522?mt=12)
- [Mirror for Sony TV](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mirror-for-sony-tv/id1173947380?mt=12)
- [Mirror for Philips TV](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mirror-for-philips-tv/id1178030238?mt=12)

The above are only some examples. In all cases you need to have good Wi-Fi for these options to work.

**NOTES:**

- The above products are from the same developer, but there are other options out there.
- I am not affiliated in any way with the above products.

Comment: This developer seems to have a very bad reputation. Most of the reviews say that the apps are so slow that they are unusable and that the apps are a rip off. Do you know of any other software or methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HDMI cable to connect your Macbook to TV.
Or you can try Chromecast or Roku dongle.
If you do not like using hardware devices, then you can try [LetsView](https://letsview.com/?apptype=apst). This is a free screen mirroring tool that can help mirroring Mac to TV wirelessly.